# How to pick a color and save as RGB on Laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I am trying to store RGB value in the database (like "255,255,255" for my laravel project. So that I can use it on a custom style of a div. So far I only found this code to select color in form. (which stores as hex)

```
{{ Form::input('color', 'color', null, array('class' => 'input-big')) }}
```

Problem for me is that I want to use the color as RGB so that I can use it with different opacity levels:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba( {{ $post->category->color . ",0.5" }} ) 0%, rgba( {{ $post->category->color . ",0.25" }} ) 100%);
```

Comment: You should avoid storing comma-separated values like that for colors. Instead, store them in any of the following formats that are recognised as valid CSS colors: (A) a [named colour](http://www.crockford.com/wrrrld/color.html), e.g. `white`, (B) in RGB(A) format, e.g. `rgb(255,255,255)` or `rgba(255,255,255,1)`, or (C) in hexadecimal format, e.g. `#fff` or `#ffffff`. In this case you can use a simple regex + logic to interconvert between the formats (hex <-> rgba is simply hexadecimal to decimal conversion), and avoid needed extensive logic to parse the colors into a valid CSS colour.

Comment: I am really lost. I forgot to say that I am a beginner. Only thing I know about converting hex to decimal is 'hexdec' function. As far as I understand I need to do something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#80796) That's why I wanted to learn is it possible to store it as RGB. I mean it's okay if I store R, G, B seperately and than I can put the commas on html.